# Testing non-existent or empty-valued keys

Tags: python

What is the truth condition for a key existing in a dictionary AND having a non-empty value?
Keys with empty values are to be ignored in our used-case.

Comment: `if dict.get(key):`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for k in some_dict:
    if k:
        #Do your stuff
```

It depends on what do you mean by non-empty? empty tuples, Nones, empty strings? my code will also exclude `0` and `False`, I don't know if it's relevant in your case

Answer (score 0):

```
if key in dictionary and dictionary[key] != "":
     do_something()
```

As Darth notes depends what you mean by empty but you can substitute any necessary values into this syntax.

Comment: It would be empty string or None in our case - but I was looking for a single check if one was available,rather than 'and'

Comment: I don't know of any where you don't have to do an and statement since you want to know if it's a blank string and if it's potentially None (although None and exists can be checked in 1)